# How to get the menu after login in master page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

H had created a master page with a menu div. I made index page as a login page, so I use the login control in index.aspx which is registered under the master page.

Now my question is how can I hide the menu div which is in master page until the user does login, after the user doing successful login the menu div  should appear to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this code in my MasterPage

```
               <% if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) { %>

                  <div>navigation html when is authenticated</div>

               <% } else { %>

              <div>navigation html when is NOT authenticated</div>

                <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your master page, you can do something like this:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Welcome back, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
}
else 
{
    <!-- Put login form here. -->
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a @ MasterType directive in the content page. In the directive, set the VirtualPath attribute to the location of the master page

Then use Master.FindControl

```
void Page_Load()
{
// Gets a reference to a TextBox control inside 
// a ContentPlaceHolder
ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
TextBox mpTextBox;
mpContentPlaceHolder = 
  (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
if(mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
{
    mpTextBox = 
        (TextBox) mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("TextBox1");
    if(mpTextBox != null)
    {
        mpTextBox.Text = "TextBox found!";
    }
}

// Gets a reference to a Label control that not in 
// a ContentPlaceHolder
Label mpLabel = (Label) Master.FindControl("masterPageLabel");
if(mpLabel != null)
{
    Label1.Text = "Master page label = " + mpLabel.Text;
}
```

}

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

Comment: This is tagged for MVC3, your answer doesn't apply.

Comment: It's also tagged "just" asp.net, so it does apply. Maybe you should flag the poster for overtagging. :-P